# How to hide some of a class's fields in C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to open-source a project, but I have a header file that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  int bar;
  int super_secret_field;
};
```

I want the open-sourced header to have the `bar` field, but not the `super_secret_field`.  I still want a closed-source version with `super_secret_field`.

I can't use two separate header files, because then the classes using `Foo` will have weird includes. I could do something hacky with #includes and then strip them out in the released version, but I'd rather not.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What about [PIMPL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) ?

Comment: Yup, that would totally work.  Write an answer and I'll accept it. Can't believe I didn't think of that... TGIF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the solution to your problem is the [PIMPL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) idiom.

In your case it would look something like:

```
// .h
class SecretType; // forward decl

class Foo {
 public:
  int bar;
  SecretType* secret_field;
};
```

and in the .cpp you would have the include the header  which contains `SecretType`'s declaration. This in effect hides the details of `SecretType` from the users of your library.

P.S: I changed the type from int to a class to make the explanation a bit more complete.

Comment: `secret_field` should really be private here, to discourage users from messing with it. And you add some public methods that let the users do what they need to do.

Comment: For future reference, Guru of the Week on PIMPL: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/ and http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is for PIMPL idiom where-in your header is just an interface with redirection to private implementation in your compilation units.